# GPS reading error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my app, am getting latitude and longitude detail from CLlocationmanager and I draw overlay on map using those details. Sometime I see that even though I travel on the path(Highway road),GPS fetching wrong details so my map app drew overlay beyond the place where am really traveling. It shows like am driving on buildings and river and trees. Could anyone please help me the correct this error please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error. This is the accuracy of the GPS signal. It's possible to get the best accuracy as possible defining `locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;`, where `locationManager` is an object of type `CLLocationManager`.
However it may not be possible to always get the exact position of the user.

Comment: Ya I accept this. Even I used kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation for desired accuracy. We know this but when some people use our app when face this situation, to them it look like its some error in the app. Thats what am afraid about and thanks for taking time to reply me.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this is out of our control. I'm also developing a module in my app that tracks user's position and this low accuracy harms its use...

Answer (score 0):

Your GPS *will* have errors, that is unavoidable. You have two choices: Either use the GPS data as it is, or use your maps information to find where you think the GPS is. For example, if the GPS is moving at more than 10 mph and has been on a street or close to a street, then you could guess that it is still on the same street and change the coordinates. That is very tricky, however, because you don't know what the actual situation is.